# Why delay() not working?

Tags: jquery

Good day.

I want to make the script started working after 2 seconds after the page loads.

For this i use script:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#searchbanner").animate( {width: "515"}, 1500 );
}, 2000);​
```

but not work...

tell me please how right make?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use .delay() together with .animate() in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247772/can-i-use-delay-together-with-animate-in-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using jQuery's `delay()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchbanner").delay(2000).animate( {width: "515"}, 1500 );
});
```

This delays the execution of later functions for a given time; in this case, it will wait 2000 milliseconds before running the `.animate()` method. More information can be found [on the jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

*EDIT: As one of the comments noted, part of the original problem may be the timing of when you are running your `setTimeout` call; if it is during the loading of the page then the time given is relative to when the script runs, not when the page has completed its loading. By using jQuery's `.ready()` method the execution waits until the entire document is completely loaded.*

Comment: the +1 is for the `$(document).ready` cause that may be the problem.

Comment: @NULL Wrote that by instinct, but could be a secondary problem - will add a note, thanks.

Comment: not work right - http://testwork.ru/10003/
block top with words "TEXT FOR TEST HEADER"

Comment: @AlexN I'm looking at the source of that page, and only seeing your original code - which is throwing an error.

Comment: @AdrianWragg see now please - line 93

Comment: @AlexN You still have your original, non-delayed, code there - line 108. Incidentally, you can chain jQuery commands into one, so may be able to write `$("#searchbanner").css("width","100px").delay(2000).animate( {width: "515px"}, 1500 );`

Comment: @AdrianWragg line 108 - it action for `$("#krest").on('click',function(){`  code when need change (when shoild start when page load) up - on line 93

Comment: @AlexN I do notice a jump 2 seconds after loading as the banner resizes; its possible jQuery cannot calculate the "starting" width properly so you may want to code that value into the CSS. On a clean page, http://jsfiddle.net/WTmgs/, the solution I've provided works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your code:

- If the DOM isn't loaded after the two seconds the timeout have specified the selector wont work, to fix that you can use `jQuery(function($) {})` which is the same as `jQuery(document).ready(function() {})`
- The width value is a string try change that to a number or add the pixel to the end:

---

```
jQuery(function($) { // <-- This makes local $ === jQuery no matter what.
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#searchbanner").animate({width: 515}, 1500);
    }, 2000);​ //                           ^ See changed it to a number
});
```

Comment: the problem is that the script runs immediately without having to wait two seconds

Answer (score 0):

it take 3500 second to execute

2000 take settimeout
1500 animation callback function

**take 2000 second now**

```
   setTimeout(function() {
      $("#searchbanner").animate( {width: "515"} ); }
      , 2000);​
```

**take 1500 second now**

```
  $("#searchbanner").animate( {width: "515"},1500 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `delay`, the jQuery method, but `setTimeout`, the JavaScript method, and the issue could be with the placement of your code. If you're not waiting for the document to load and just trying to execute this then a number of things could go wrong. Such as elements not being loaded, jQuery not being loaded, for instance.

Wait for the document to load simply by encapsulating your jQuery in `$(document).ready(function() { });`

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#searchbanner").animate( {"width": "515"}, 1500 ) }
  , 2000);​
```

Comment: This appears to just be the original code with a semi-colon removed.