# Is it possible to use jQuery .on and hover?

Tags: jquery

I have a `<ul>` that is populated with javascript after the initial page load.  I'm currently using `.bind` with `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

The project just updated to jQuery 1.7 so I have the option to use `.on`, but I can't seem to get it to work with `hover`.  Is it possible to use `.on` with `hover`?

**EDIT**: The elements I'm binding to are loaded with javascript after the document loads.  That's why I'm using `on` and not just `hover`.

Comment: From a comment below - **hover event support in On() was deprecated in jQuery 1.8, and removed in jQuery 1.9**. Try with a combination of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, as suggested by calebthebrewer.

Answer (score 799, accepted):

(*Look at the last edit in this answer if you need to use `.on()` with elements populated with JavaScript*)

Use this for elements that are not populated using JavaScript:

```
$(".selector").on("mouseover", function () {
    //stuff to do on mouseover
});
```

`.hover()` has its own handler: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

If you want to do multiple things, chain them in the `.on()` handler like so:

```
$(".selector").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse enter
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse leave
    }
});
```

According to the answers provided below you can use `hover` with `.on()`, but:

> Although strongly discouraged for new code, you may see the
> pseudo-event-name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string
> "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those
> two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine
> whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not confuse the
> "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one
> or two functions.

Also, there are no performance advantages to using it and it's more bulky than just using `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`.  The answer I provided requires less code and is the proper way to achieve something like this.

**EDIT**

It's been a while since this question was answered and it seems to have gained some traction.  The above code still stands, but I did want to add something to my original answer.

While I prefer using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (helps me understand whats going on in the code) with `.on()` it is just the same as writing the following with `hover()`

```
$(".selector").hover(function () {
    //stuff to do on mouse enter
}, 
function () {
    //stuff to do on mouse leave
});
```

Since the original question did ask how they could properly use `on()` with `hover()`, I thought I would correct the usage of `on()` and didn't find it necessary to add the `hover()` code at the time.

**EDIT DECEMBER 11, 2012**

Some new answers provided below detail how `.on()` should work if the `div` in question is populated using JavaScript.  For example, let's say you populate a `div` using jQuery's `.load()` event, like so:

```
(function ($) {
    //append div to document body
    $('<div class="selector">Test</div>').appendTo(document.body);
}(jQuery));
```

The above code for `.on()` would not stand.  Instead, you should modify your code slightly, like this:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse enter
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse leave
    }
}, ".selector"); //pass the element as an argument to .on
```

This code will work for an element populated with JavaScript after a `.load()` event has happened.  Just change your argument to the appropriate selector.

> **EDIT JAN 2023**

I know this is an older one but I thought id share this as it confused me a little bit, was going around in circles. But I applied the domsubtreemodifer logic that you have to target the wrapper.

**Im unsure if jquery has changed over time but, You also have to include the container now that you are adding the target to.**

So for example:

Your dom looks like this:

```
<div class="taggable">
</div>
```

Your adding a div like so in jquery

```
$('.taggable').append('<div class="close"><div>');
```

Your DOM will end up looking like this.

```
<div class="taggable">
   <div class="close"></div>
</div>
```

So in order for you mouse event to work you need to target the container AS well as the element you have added

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
    }
}, ".taggable .close");
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('.taggable').append('<div class="close">testme<div>');
});


    $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
        console.log('mouseenter');
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
        console.log('mouseleave');
        }
    }, ".taggable .close");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="taggable">
</div>
```

Comment: While you're right about `.hover()` having its own handler, the OP's question was "Is it possible to use .on with hover?" @JonMcIntosh's answer and jsFiddle demonstrates yes.

Comment: Sure, it's possible.. But there is no need to use it with `.on()` when just using `.hover()` by itself will produce the same results.

Comment: @Scott, please note that JonMcIntosh's answer does not answer my question because he's only using half of the hover functionality.

Comment: @Toast this is the answer you are looking for..  The `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` function gives you power to do different things while using `.on()`

Comment: hover removed as of 1.9+ version of jQuery

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Still important info for people working with versions of jQuery 1.9 or earlier.

Comment: @SethenMaleno - exactly, and your `.on()` solution works with either removing the pseudo hover event and using the real ones. I like the first one you illustrated with mouseenter/mouseleave +1 for that

Comment: @SethenMaleno Thanks for the last bit with the `.on()` method to use it with populated DOM. Was using 2 `.on()` calls instaed of 1 clean

Comment: Actually, the only reason I came here, was to see if I use .hover() can I use .off() to remove it. This seems like the only reason to bother, otherwise I would use .hover() without question. It seems I need to use unbind() in combination with .hover() because off() only removes events bound with on()

Answer (score 104):

None of these solutions worked for me when mousing over/out of objects created after the document has loaded as the question requests. I know this question is old but I have a solution for those still looking:

```
$("#container").on('mouseenter', '.selector', function() {
    //do something
});
$("#container").on('mouseleave', '.selector', function() {
    //do something
});
```

This will bind the functions to the selector so that objects with this selector made after the document is ready will still be able to call it.

Comment: This one has the proper solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608145/jquery-on-method-with-multiple-event-handlers-to-one-selector

Comment: This is how I got it working too, I found the accepted answer putting the selector before the .on didn't work following a .load() event but this does.

Comment: @calebthebrewer Edited my answer, it now takes into account elements populated with JavaScript.

Comment: Using `mouseover` and `mouseout` events here will cause the code to continually fire as the user moves the mouse around inside the element. I think `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are more appropriate since it'll only fire once upon entry.

Comment: I tried replacing my hover events with the jquery supplied here, but it led to undesirable effects and so I reverted my code back to using hover. The moral of the story is sometimes hover just works better.

Comment: using document as the root element is not best practice, since its performance hungry. you are monitoring document, while with load() you most of the time manipulate just a part of the website (f.ex. #content). so its better to try to narrow it down to the element, thats manipulated..

Answer (score 19):

I'm not sure what the rest of your Javascript looks like, so I won't be able to tell if there is any interference. But [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) works just fine as an event with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$("#foo").on("hover", function() {
  // disco
});
```

If you want to be able to utilize its events, use the returned object from the event:

```
$("#foo").on("hover", function(e) {
  if(e.type == "mouseenter") {
    console.log("over");
  }
  else if (e.type == "mouseleave") {
    console.log("out");
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hmUPP/2/

Comment: How does this handle the separate functions for on/off that hover uses?  Ex:  `$('#id').hover(function(){ //on }, function(){ //off});`

Comment: To me, this isn't necessary..  You don't need to use `.on()` with `hover` when you can just as easily get rid of `.on()` and replace it with the `.hover()` function and get the same results.  Isn't jQuery about writing less code??

Comment: @Toast it doesn't, see my answer below to see how to perform `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` functions with `.on()`

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the utilization of both event types. This works just the same as Sethen's answer but has a different flavor.

Comment: **`hover` event support in `On()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.8, and removed in jQuery 1.9.**

Answer (score 11):

Just surfed in from the web and felt I could contribute. I noticed that with the above code posted by @calethebrewer can result in multiple calls over the selector and unexpected behaviour for example: -

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.selector', function() {
   //do something
});
$(document).on('mouseout', '.selector', function() {
   //do something
});
```

This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TWskH/12/ illustraits my point. When animating elements such as in plugins I have found that these multiple triggers result in unintended behavior which may result in the animation or code being called more than is necessary.

My suggestion is to simply replace with mouseenter/mouseleave: -

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.selector', function() {
   //do something
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.selector', function() {
   //do something
});
```

Although this prevented multiple instances of my animation from being called, I eventually went with mouseover/mouseleave as I needed to determine when children of the parent were being hovered over.

Comment: This answer actually provided a working solution to adding a hover event for a document selector. +1

Answer (score 11):

jQuery hover function gives mouseover and mouseout functionality.

### $(selector).hover(inFunction,outFunction);

```
$(".item-image").hover(function () {
    // mouseover event codes...
}, function () {
    // mouseout event codes...
});
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp

Comment: definitely works. you got a down vote because some people are dump! Thanks mate

Comment: He gets a downvote because if you need late binding, which the "on" method is about, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#MyTableData").on({

 mouseenter: function(){

    //stuff to do on mouse enter
    $(this).css({'color':'red'});

},
mouseleave: function () {
    //stuff to do on mouse leave
    $(this).css({'color':'blue'});

}},'tr');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can you use [**`.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with `hover` by doing what the Additional Notes section says:

> Although strongly discouraged for new code, you may see the
>   pseudo-event-name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string
>   "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those
>   two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine
>   whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not confuse the
>   "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one
>   or two functions.

That would be to do the following:

```
$("#foo").on("hover", function(e) {

    if (e.type === "mouseenter") { console.log("enter"); }
    else if (e.type === "mouseleave") { console.log("leave"); }

});
```

---

**EDIT (note for jQuery 1.8+ users):**

> Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a
>   shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single
>   event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine
>   event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave.
>   Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method,
>   which accepts one or two functions.

Comment: This is just more work when it can easily be done by using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`... I know, this doesn't answer OP's original question, but still, using `hover` in this way, isn't wise.

Comment: Doing it this way follows exactly how the jQuery team suggests you do it in accordance to the OP's question.  However, as the jQuery team suggests, it's strongly discouraged for new code.  But, it's still the correct answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @Scott - you were faster than me :-). @Sethen - both ways will work, but the asker requested the functionality with `.hover()`.

Comment: Understandably so, but still, I think OP was looking for a solution for a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` rather than just making it work with `hover`.  If there is no real reason to use `hover` for performance reasons, why use it when it's strongly discouraged for new code?

Comment: @Sethen - His question stated what he was using (`mousenter` and `mouseleave`) and then asked a totally different question with regards to the new jQuery version's `.on()` and `hover`. Your answer being accepted doesn't do justice to the question asked is all I'm saying.  I agree with the fact that I would personally do it your way, but the answer to the question / title of this post is what I posted.

Comment: Actually, he said he was using `mouseover` and `mouseout` which can be used as there own functions.  He said nothing about `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`

Comment: @Sethen - You are right, I misspoke. =) Still, I hold my stance.

Comment: @Scott Totally, I understand.

Comment: **`hover` event support in `On()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.8, and removed in jQuery 1.9.**

Answer (score 5):

You can provide one or multiple event types separated by a space.

So `hover` equals `mouseenter mouseleave`.

This is my sugession:

```
$("#foo").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
    // do some stuff
});
```

Comment: I like jQ's decision to depreciate this parameter. Prior version 1.8, using  to hover as a namespace didn't coincide with the DOM event, hover, no relation.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it to have as a condition in an other event, I solved it this way:

```
$('.classname').hover(
     function(){$(this).data('hover',true);},
     function(){$(this).data('hover',false);}
);
```

Then in another event, you can easily use it:

```
 if ($(this).data('hover')){
      //...
 }
```

(I see some using `is(':hover')` to solve this. But this is not (yet) a valid jQuery selector and does not work in all compatible browsers)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older one but I thought id share this as it confused me a little bit, was going around in circles. But I applied the domsubtreemodifer logic that you have to target the wrapper.

The accepted answer states that you target the selector, however I found this wouldn't work for me. You also have to include the container that you are adding the target to.

So for example:

Your dom looks like this:

```
<div class="taggable">
</div>
```

Your adding a div like so in jquery

```
$('.taggable').append('<div class="close"><div>');
```

Your DOM will end up looking like this.

```
<div class="taggable">
   <div class="close"></div>
</div>
```

So in order for you mouse event to work you need to target the container AS well as the element you have added

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
    }
}, ".taggable .close");
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('.taggable').append('<div class="close">testme<div>');
});


    $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
        console.log('mouseenter');
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
        console.log('mouseleave');
        }
    }, ".taggable .close");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="taggable">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

The jQuery plugin hoverIntent http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html goes much further than the naive approaches listed here. While they certainly work, they might not necessarily behave how users expect.

The strongest reason to use hoverIntent is the **timeout** feature. It allows you to do things like prevent a menu from closing because a user drags their mouse slightly too far to the right or left before they click the item they want. It also provides capabilities for not activating hover events in a barrage and waits for focused hovering.

Usage example:

```
var config = {    
 sensitivity: 3, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)    
 interval: 200, // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval    
 over: makeTall, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
 timeout: 500, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
 out: makeShort // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)
};
$("#demo3 li").hoverIntent( config )
```

Further explaination of this can be found on https://stackoverflow.com/a/1089381/37055