# JQuery - Use hover() and on()

Tags: jquery

i try to use jquery's on()-Method in combination with hover(). I want that the user hovers over a div, gets a value displayed and when moving his mouse away from that div see the old value again, but this is not working... Does anybody have a clue?

```
$('#content').on('hover', '.player_marktwert_box',
    function() {
    var playerValue = $(this).html();
        $(this).html("test");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).html(playerValue);
    }
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it's deprecated: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var playerValue;

$(".selector").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        playerValue = $(this).html();
        $(this).html("test");
    }, 
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).html(playerValue);
    }
});
```

Please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover) question for more details. Since playerValue is outside of the scope of the event it will have a value that persists. Depending on your scripting this could work, depending on whether it is possible to mouse over multiple `.selector` elements at once.

Answer (score 5):

`.hover` is actually just a shortcut and not a true event name. It simply expands to `mouseenter` for the first function and `mouseleave` for the second.

So, you could use `.on("mouseenter", "...",` and `.on("mouseleave", "...",`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i then use the "old" value of the div in "mouseleave"?

Comment: @Torben: You could store and retrieve it using `.data` on the element. (Your current code wouldn't share the variable `playerValue` by the way.)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#content').on({
    mouseenter: function() { ... },
    mouseleave: function() { ... }
},'.player_marktwert_box');
```

This is the proper way to delegate `hover` events without using the `$.hover()` shortcut

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Just according to `pimvdb`'s idea)

```
$('#content').on('mouseenter', '.player_marktwert_box', function() {
    var playerValue = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("test").data('playerValue',playerValue);
}).on('mouseleave', '.player_marktwert_box', function() {
    $(this).html($(this).data('playerValue'));
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/9JHnq/1/)

Answer (score 1):

**HERE IS THE FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/collabcoders/ses7G/**

```
var originalValue;
$('#content').on('mouseenter', '.player_marktwert_box', function(){
    originalValue = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("test");
}).on('mouseleave', '.player_marktwert_box', function() {
    $(this).html(originalValue);
});
```

​

Answer (score 1):

A simple example:

```
var val=$('#foo').html();
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '#foo', function(ev) {
    $(this).html((ev.type == 'mouseenter') ? 'test' : val);
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Max9s/)**

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to not just use .hover?

```
var playerValue = $('.player_marktwert_box').html();
$('.player_marktwert_box').hover(
   function() {
      $(this).html("TEST :)");
   },
   function () {
      $(this).html(playerValue);
   }
);
```

DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/M93mM/1/

Comment: The only reason I could see if Torben plans of having multiple instances of the .player_marktwert_box div.

Comment: having a wrapper with .on is the best practice for that because you will not initialize every instance of the .player_martwer_box

Comment: Yes, i have multiple instances of that div.