# How to create drop down menus on dynamically generated div fields

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, dynamically-generated

I am loading divs with information from the database using php code:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $stmt->rowCount(); $i++){
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $name = $row['uc_name'];
    $image_url = $row['uc_image'];
    $color = $row['uc_color'];
```

The creates a box for however many rows there are: http://jsfiddle.net/pKR5t/1/

I am trying to create a drop down menu for each item retrieved from the database. When the user hovers over `class="header"`, the drop down menu should show but the list inside should be pertaining to that of the box hovered:

[image]

I believe I can use the `.on()` function to accomplish this but I am completely lost on how to use it. Any help on getting this accomplished would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pKR5t/12/ The menu is the same for all three except goto links dynamically change

Comment: If you are loading it dynamically via ajax, you can tie the handler to the document, so any new boxes you add also have the dropdown working: http://jsfiddle.net/pKR5t/20/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `on` and `hover` you will want to use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events like so:

```
$("div.box div.header").on("mouseenter", function() { //mouseenter event
    var currentBox = $(this).closest("div.box");
    var currentTitleText = $(this).find("div.title").html();

    //popup the list

}).on("mouseleave", function() { //mouseleave event
    //close the list
});
```

For some additional info, [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover).

**EDIT**

Updated `mouseover` and `mouseout` to the slightly better `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without javascript using css.

If you insert your hover box inside your header div you can use css `:hover` to hide and show it on hover.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="title">PHP Row 1</div>
    <div class="hoverBox">
        <div class="hoverBoxTitle">Hover</div>
        <div class="hoverBoxContent">Hover Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.hoverBox {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 170px;
    width:170px;
    height:90px;
    background:#333333;
    z-index: 100;
}
.header:hover .hoverBox {
    display: block;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pKR5t/5/)**