# using on() with hover - jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover

This is what I have:

```
$('#blah').hover(function(){
    $('etc').show();
}, function(){
    $('etc').hide();
});
```

This works just fine, now I want the exact above code working live with on() method:

```
$('#blah').on('hover', function(){
    $('#etc').show();
}, function(){
    $('#etc').hide();
});
```

But this is not working, anybody knows why? but also this works:

```
$('#blah').on('hover', function(){
    $('#etc').show();
});
```

When I'm using on() method, the callback function is not working, so I'm using mouseover() and mouseleave() with on() and it's working, I just wanted to know why hover callback is not working with on(), that's so simpler than using 2 events....

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [JQuery](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js) source code, `hover` is not included in the event list that triggered leading to JQuery `.on()`

```
jQuery.each( ("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick " +
    "mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
    "change select submit keydown keypress keyup error contextmenu").split(" "), function( i, name ) {

    // Handle event binding
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( data, fn ) {
        return arguments.length > 0 ?
            this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
            this.trigger( name );
    };
});
```

It is because `.hover()` is just a shortcut for JQuery `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`

```
jQuery.fn.hover = function( fnOver, fnOut ) {
    return this.mouseenter( fnOver ).mouseleave( fnOut || fnOver );
};
```

I hope this brief explanation provides little guidance.

Answer (score 3):

from Jquery docs. [Jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes)

> Deprecated as of jQuery 1.8: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for
>   the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler
>   for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to
>   determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not
>   confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which
>   accepts one or two functions.

```
$("div.test").on({
  mouseenter: function(){
    $(this).addClass("inside");
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    $(this).removeClass("inside");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use mouseenter and mouseleave for hover. Check using hover with on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover).

```
$("#blah").on(
{
    mouseenter: function() 
    {
        //stuff to do on mouseover
    },
    mouseleave: function()
    {
        //stuff to do on mouseleave
    }
});
```

Use toggle to show / hide,

```
$('#blah').on('hover', function(){
    $('#etc').toggle();
});
```

Comment: not relevant, I already found a solution to the problem, I just wanted to know why it's not working, but a good point, thanks

Comment: @behz4d it was not working because when you use hover using on it only has single call back see my answer..

Answer (score 1):

It's because `hover` is not really a browser event, in fact its just a shorthand for calling

```
 $(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);
```

Using with the `.on('hover')` form [have been deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes) as of version 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 jQuery.on("hover","#blah", function..)
```

Or you can use toggle feature of jQuery too

Comment: what's the differance ? you are passing a context to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will not work because when you use `.on()` with `hover` then `hover` event just have one call-back function instead you can use multiple events in `.on()`

Try

```
$("DOM").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        // Handle mouseenter...
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        // Handle mouseleave...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use toggle()

```
$('#blah').on('hover', function(){
   $('#etc').toggle();
});
```