# A hover event I have does not work after an ajax load, it only works on initial page load

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue where a hover event I have does not work after an ajax load, it only works on initial page load. This is the code I am using currently:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.like').hover(
        function () {
          var id=this.id;
          values=id.split('.');
                  id=values[0];
                  type=values[1];
          var arrow_box_id='arrow_box'+'_'+id;
          document.getElementById(arrow_box_id).style.display = "";
          jQuery.ajax({
                 url: 'fetch_likes_comment.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data:{ 
                     id: id, 
                     type:type
           },
           beforeSend: function() {
               },
           complete: function() { 
               }
             }).done(function( msg ) { 
                 document.getElementById(arrow_box_id).innerHTML = msg;
               });
        }, 
            function () {
           var id=this.id;
           values=id.split('.');
                   id=values[0];
                   type=values[1];
           var arrow_box_id='arrow_box'+'_'+id;
                   document.getElementById(arrow_box_id).style.display = "none";
            }
    );
});
```

Comment: I am guessing you need to use delegate to bind the event. http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: @skajfes Delegation is deprecated (superseded by `.on` to be precise).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use jQuery .on and hover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover)

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
$(document).on("mouseover",'.like',function()
{
    //stuff to do on mouseover
})."mouseout",'.like',function()
{
    //stuff to do on mouseout
});
```

Comment: You also need a `mouseout` handler.

Comment: Ahh..I forgot that.Thanks for the spot.

Answer (score 0):

`.bind('event'...)` triggers (.hover is an alias to that statement) bind only to existing elements. If you generate new elements in your code they will be unaffected.

To rectify this, use the new `.on` statement:

```
$('body').on( // No error, we bind the handler to the DOM body.
    'mouseover',
    '.like', // This is the selector that reacts to your handler.
    function(){ blagh; }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('hover', '.like', function () {
    // or you can also use
    //$('.like').on('hover', function () {
        var id = this.id;
        values = id.split('.');
        id = values[0];
        type = values[1];
        var arrow_box_id = 'arrow_box' + '_' + id;
        document.getElementById(arrow_box_id).style.display = "";
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : 'fetch_likes_comment.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                id : id,
                type : type
            },
            beforeSend : function () {},
            complete : function () {}

        }).done(function (msg) {
            document.getElementById(arrow_box_id).innerHTML = msg;
        });
    }, function () {
        var id = this.id;
        values = id.split('.');
        id = values[0];
        type = values[1];
        var arrow_box_id = 'arrow_box' + '_' + id;
        document.getElementById(arrow_box_id).style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Neeraj, Thanks for the reply i tried with these two $('body').on('hover', '.like', function () {
    and
$('.like').on('hover', function () but still i have the same  issue.

Comment: @Suhaskn: can you plz share your ajax output. let me see what is coming via ajax response. I am considering that in your ajax response you are getting dynamically .like class and you are trying to fire hover event on that..