# .on() on a set of <li> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to use the .on() jQuery function for call something when the `<li>` that I have, are hovered.

When I try to do something like this:

```
$("body").on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                console.warn('dansl\'body');
                //stuff to do on mouse enter
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                console.warn('sorti');
                //stuff to do on mouse leave
            }
});
```

It works, i receive the messages when my body is hovered. But when i try to replace "body" by "li", it's not working anymore. How can I apply a .on() on a set of `<li>` ?

PS: My `<li>` are generated after the document load.

Comment: Is the .on code wrapped in a document ready block?

Comment: Or are the `li` elements dynamically added?

Comment: You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: The .on code is not wrapped in ready block. And, as i said in my post, the li are generated after, dynamically added yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need event delegation for attaching events to dynamically added dom:

**Update:**
`.hover()` can not be used with `.on()`. You can instead use:

```
$("body").on({
mouseenter: function () {
    console.warn('dansl\'body');
    //stuff to do on mouse enter
},
mouseleave: function () {
    console.warn('sorti');
    //stuff to do on mouse leave
}
}, "li"); //pass the element as an argument to .on
```

Comment: I'd recommend to look for the closest static parent element of `<li>` to make the code running faster.

Comment: @VisioN: i totally agree to that. But OP didnt provided the information that how does elements are added.

Comment: It's not working... No error, nothin.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar i add the li on a static UL

Comment: Two problems: 1) `hover` maps to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, not `mouseover` and `mouseout`, 2) [`hover` cannot be used with `on()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: thanks....seriously did not knew it.

Comment: Ok it works thank you. As everybody say, perhaps that you should replace `body` by `ul` in your post. For access the direct parent. And for the future users which could have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
    // cause some mayhem here
}).on("mouseleave", "li", function() {
    // use this to restore order
});
```

What happens is the events are bound before the elements exist, so they don't receive the event.  When you bind it on the document like this it will be present for all elements that match the selector, even dynamically created ones.

Comment: this works, but you should probably use a closer parent to `li` instead of `document`

Comment: There's no reason to split the individual events out into separate calls to `.on()`; the function supports passing an object with events/handlers as key/value pairs, as well as a selector for delegation. In other words, the only change to the code in the question should be adding ,"li" to the `.on()` call, as well as more specific selector to call it on (the static `<ul>` element).

Comment: Sam Creamer does have a point though, binding to the most direct parent of the li's is more proper and will execute faster.  I'm lazy, however, and tend to use document for everything.  It's "bad" practice, but not terrible.

Answer (score -1):

To sum up all the solutions provided here, since your target elements are loaded dynamically you may better use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) instead of binding events after elements creation.

For a single event the second argument of `on` method is used as a selector for the target elements:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    // "dynamic" <li> element is clicked
});
```

For multiple events the following approach can be used:

```
$('ul').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        // <li> receives 'mouseenter'
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        // <li> receives 'mouseleave'
    }
}, 'li');
```

To make code running faster you should bind events to the closest static parent of the target element(s).

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qb95X/

Comment: I can't accept your answer as the solution. You just copy pasted what others have answered. PS: The downvote is not from me...

Comment: @Superdrac Not really. This solution is not unique, as the problem is rather trivial and was asked on StackOverflow hundreds of times. Moreover, I have summed up all the facts regarding event delegation and proposed the workable solution with a DEMO in contrast to either wrong or excessive solutions provided around.