# jQuery - On hover with extended selector does not work

Tags: jquery, html

On hover I want to call a function. If the element has the class "disabled_btn" it shall be supressed. Why is mode code not working? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qa7co8y4/)

html

```
<button id="btn" > hover here</button>
```

JS

```
$('#btn:not(.disabled-btn)').on('hover', function(){ 
                alert('click');
            });
```

Comment: bit more explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover

Comment: $( "#btn:not(.disabled-btn)" ).hover(function() {
   alert('click');
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `mouseover` instead of `hover`:

```
$('#btn:not(.disabled-btn)').on(' mouseover', function () {   
    alert('click');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qa7co8y4/2/

Comment: After reading the question again, I think this works better for vuvus needs. `hover()` will trigger the event again on `mouseleave`, and that's not what he wants. Got confused by what he had already tried. I think this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.hover()` instead of `on("hover")`. Like this:

```
$('#btn:not(.disabled-btn)').hover(function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qa7co8y4/3/

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like `hover` on JS you need to use `mouseenter` or `mouseover` instead.

```
$('#btn:not(.disabled-btn)').on(' mouseenter', function () {   
    alert('click');
});
```

or

```
$('#btn:not(.disabled-btn)').on(' mouseover', function () {   
    alert('click');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ive update your code for you see [Updated Code](http://jsfiddle.net/qa7co8y4/)

```js
$('#btn:not(.disabled-btn)').hover(function(){ 
                    alert('click');
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" class=""> hover here</button>
```