# Cannot hover on dynamically generated div element

Tags: jquery, css

I am currently dynamically generating the `row` and `col-xs-6 col-sm-4` inside the `#locations-content` div element.

```
<div id="locations-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/boston.jpg" id="Boston-img-popup"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get image to fade on hover, but it doesn't appear to be working. Is there something wrong with my code:

```
$('#locations-content').on('hover', '.row > .col-xs-6.col-sm-4', function(event){
    $(this).find('img').fadeTo('slow', 0.4);  
    $(this).find('img').fadeTo('slow', 1);  
});
```

Comment: Works fine on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcmgcbj/)

Comment: @ArturFilipiak The fiddle would be a better demonstration if you put the `for` loop _after_ the event binding.

Comment: @Barmar , right :-) Updated comment

Comment: Can you provide your jsFiddle? How are you generating the row?

Comment: Look here: [Is it possible to use jQuery .on and hover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to use mouseenter instead of hover

```
$('#locations-content').on('mouseenter', '.row > .col-xs-6.col-sm-4', function(event){
  $(this).find('img').fadeTo('slow', 0.4);  
  $(this).find('img').fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
```