# Jquery: Attaching "each" to an "on" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, each

I have a list of results, and I added an *hover* event to it using jQuery, so the title will be colored red.

It works just fine.

```
<li><a class="hoverbox"></a><h1 class="ttl">Result 1</h1></li>
<li><a class="hoverbox"></a><h1 class="ttl">Result 2</h1></li>
<li><a class="hoverbox"></a><h1 class="ttl">Result 3</h1></li>
```

```
$(document).on({
   mouseenter: function () {
    $('.ttl').css("color","red");
   },
   mouseleave: function () {
    $('.ttl').css("color","inherit");
   }
}, ".hoverbox");
```

The thing is whenever I do mouseover on a single element, all of the elements turn red. I want only the specific element to go red.

I tried using jQuery's **each()** but couldn't wrap my head around how to use it with the given syntax.

Comment: `$('.ttl')` selects all the `.ttl` elements, how did you think it would work? Do you want the *next* `.ttl` element to be colored? Such as `$(this).next('.ttl')`?

Comment: $(this) will not work because I am not changing the specific element. I am coloring the element next to it (the title). @zzzzBov Yes. Thank you, it worked. I am sorry if the question sounds dumb (already got downvoted) but I just couldn't figure out by myself. Thanks again.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: OP, you code is not even working. You need to remove '.hoverbox' at the end. Don't know what it is doing there, but it definetly break your code.

Comment: @Mikey The code does work, I am working according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9827114/4124802) . I must use this syntax because the content is loaded dynamically.

Comment: @Django Strange, doesn't work for me https://jsfiddle.net/6ja0gv5q/1/, what version of jQuery are you on?

Comment: @Mikey Try this please to see the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/w4j5hsLh/2/

Comment: @Django I have given a CSS solution, please see answer

Comment: @Django, please consider accessibility. For example, how would someone who is unable to use a mouse access this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution without JS**

https://jsfiddle.net/w4j5hsLh/3/

```
.hoverbox{
position:absolute;
z-index:999;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
li{width:100px;height:100px;position:relative;}

li:hover > .ttl {
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: Aggh! Big thank you to everyone that helped. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you need to do this with JavaScript? This can be achieved really easily with CSS.

HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li><a class="hoverbox"></a><h1 class="ttl">Result 1</h1></li>
    <li><a class="hoverbox"></a><h1 class="ttl">Result 2</h1></li>
    <li><a class="hoverbox"></a><h1 class="ttl">Result 3</h1></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.list > li:hover .ttl {
    color: red !important; // if you have to override an already applied theme (like wordpress) 
}
```

Comment: Best solution. Don't use js for simple CSS problems.

Comment: It won't work due to z-index & position:absolute properties of the hoverbox div. Thanks though

Comment: Of course it will... If CSS can't reach it because of z-index, JavaScript should not be able to either...

Comment: @Django can you attach a screenshot of you problem?

Comment: @Django Maybe give the complete CSS for your elements. This problem should be solved with CSS.

Comment: I will do one better. I am using the Wordpress theme Listify. The results list demo can be found [here](https://demo.astoundify.com/listify/listing-region/toronto/) . Just switch _.hoverbox_ with _.job_listing-clickbox_ . As you can see, attempting `.type-job_listing.style-grid .job_listing-entry-header .job_listing-title:hover{}` just won't do anything.

Comment: @Django Not sure what I am looking for here... that said, if it is a theme, they are most probably already using CSS for hovering. This means that if you don't use a selector chain that is heavier than theirs, your's won't work. Make sure you add `!important` next to you CSS red value. That way it will override their CSS.

Comment: @justinledouxweb It is not an override problem. I have used !important. The problem is caused because .hoverbox is located on top of the title element, so you can't access it with :hover. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: @Django I can't find any `hoverbox` on the link you sent... Where do you see what we are talking about?

Comment: @justinledouxweb Sorry I did not mention it, the content is loaded dynamically. So you have to use Inspect Element on one of the boxes in the results list to see the HTML after it rendered. I have a fiddle though https://jsfiddle.net/w4j5hsLh/2/

Comment: @Django I'm still not clear what you are supposed to hover on... Please describe what to do step by step in order to see what you want. I see the results, but there does not seam to be any hover effect.

Comment: @justinledouxweb Yes, I want to create one. But using hover event on the div that contains the title does not work.

Comment: @Django AH! I see now. They are positioning the anchor on top of the container. So what you can do it put the hover of the <li> wrapping the anchor and the content. So `.job_listing:hover .job_listing-title { color: red }`

Comment: @justinledouxweb Mikey beat you to it haha, but I very much appreciate your time and effort nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to get the expected result.

```
$('.ttl').on('mouseenter',function() {
    $(this).css("color","red");
    }).on('mouseleave',function() {
    $(this).css("color","inherit");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$('.ttl')` because it refers to all the `.ttl` elements you need to use `$(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.ttl')` to select the current `.ttl` element:

```
$(document).on({
   mouseenter: function (e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.ttl').css("color","red");
   },
   mouseleave: function (e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.ttl').css("color","inherit");
   }
}, ".hoverbox");
```

However, as others have said, **using CSS is recommended over using JS**.

Comment: There are no `.ttl` elements inside `.hoverbox` elements (why I deleted my same answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do minute change if you want to attach multiple event handlers simultaneously using a plain object.

```
$('.ttl').on({        
   mouseenter: function () {
    $(this).css("color","red");
   },
   mouseleave: function () {
    $(this).css("color","inherit");
   }
});
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/w4j5hsLh/) for demo

Comment: Thank you but the "hoverbox" div has properties (position:absolute;z-index:999;) that force me to apply the "hover" to it alone.

Comment: I am not seeing any div.hoverbox but it is on a element. I have added some rules to hoverbox, you can check this https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/w4j5hsLh/1/

Comment: is a.hoverBox has any purpose?