# Dynamic background change depending on current image hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change background image of a div, depending on what image is currently hovered by mouse. I want to create a gallery, so I have a list of images. I want to display the exact same url dynamically (hovered thumbnail) as hovered as a background of the main div (hero image).

```
<div id="background">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="image/1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="image/2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="image/3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

At the beginning, the `id="background"` has default background, which should be swaped to hovered image. When the image is unhovered, the image should back to the default one.

How can I do that using jquery the easiest way? It has to be the same url as the thumbnail, so it has to be dynamic, without additional url settings in jquery script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first try

```
$('ul img').on('hover',  function(e){
    $('#background').css('background-image','url('+ $(this).attr('src')+')');
});
```

Or if you have problems with selectors

```
$('body').on('hover','ul img',  function(e){
      $('#background').css('background-image','url('+ $(this).attr('src')+')');
});
```

Also consider using mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Heres working code from your codepen:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter','img',  function(e){
      $('#hero-image').css('background-image','url('+ $(this).attr('src')+')');
});
```

Comment: it don't seems to be working in my example, please could You take a look: http://codepen.io/dawidxt/pen/VmXPvZ

Comment: I edited my codepen, but still same effect, take a look and maybe its my browser's problem? http://codepen.io/dawidxt/pen/VmXPvZ

Comment: one thing , you forgot to add jquery, in codepen settings

Comment: Indeed... silly me... sorry and thank You, it does work now ! I am wondering if there is any dynamic way to prevent the default background image on mouse leave? like in "toggle" functionality.

Comment: Just describe what happens on mouseenter and what on mouseleave ;)

Comment: when page loads, it loads with predefined background - and this background might be changed over time to other via dashboard (cms). So it will definatly  have different name. So the script should reverse the background to whatever was before hovering an ul image.

Comment: First grab var oldBg = $('#hero').css('background-image'); and use it on mouseleave.

Comment: yyy. english please :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129834/discussion-between-dawid-and-cssblaster21895).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("ul li").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('#background').css('background-image', $(this).attr('src'));
        //stuff to do on mouse enter
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('#background').css('background-image', 'default.png');
        //stuff to do on mouse leave
    } });
```

or

```
    $("ul li").hover(function () {
        $('#background').css('background-image', $(this).attr('src'));
        //stuff to do on mouse enter
    }, 
    function () {
        $('#background').css('background-image', 'default.png');
        //stuff to do on mouse leave
    });
```

for more details [Is it possible to use jQuery .on and hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover)

Comment: the on mouse leave event, has to as well be dynamic. I mean, it has to just back to previous default image, instead of static one. Because this image will be changeable via dashboard of my cms.

Comment: then it is better generate CSS dynamically, when admin changed the images. Or else generate html dynamically $('#background').css('background-image', <? echo DEFAULT_IMAGE ?>); or asp.net <% ... %> or else <div id="background" data-default-image='<? echo DEFAULT_IMAGE ?>'> and use this jQuery. .attr method.

Answer (score -1):

```html
    Try this (that is what I understand from your case )

#background {
 width:90% ;
 height:90% ;
 background:url(anyimage.jpg) no-repeat top left ;
}

#background:HOVER {
 width:100% ;
 height:100% ;
 background:url(hovered.jpg) no-repeat top left ;
}
```