# Selfmade jQuery cannot handle event properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Update: It might be the jQuery's trigger() do some extra works in testings, I opened a [issue](https://github.com/infinum/learnQuery/issues/6) on github.

=====

I'm following [learnQuery](https://learnquery.infinum.co/) to build my simple jQuery. Now working on DOM event , implement `on()` and `off()` function. They provided some testings, I can't pass some of them.

Here is my code:   (**And you can clone [this branch](https://github.com/EzioKissshot/LearnQuery.git) ,run `06.event_listeners/runner.html` to run the testing**)

```
"use strict";

function isEmpty(str) {
    return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}

// listener use to bind to DOM element, call corresponding functions when event firing.
function geneEventListener(event) {
  console.log('gene');
  let type = Object.keys(this.handlers).find(type=>type===event.type);
  if (!type) return;
  let functions = this.handlers[type];
  functions.forEach(f=>f.apply(this,event));
}

// cache elements which bound event listener
let Cache = function () {
  this.elements = [];
  this.uid = 1;
};

Cache.prototype = {
  constructor:Cache,
  init:function (element) {
    if(!element.uid) element.uid = this.uid++;
    if(!element.handlers) element.handlers = {};
    if(!element.lqListener) element.lqListener = geneEventListener.bind(element);
    this.elements.push(element);
  },
  removeElement:function (uid) {
    this.elements.splice(this.elements.findIndex(e=>e.uid===uid),1);
  },
  removeType:function (uid,type) {
    if(this.get(uid)) delete this.get(uid).handlers[type];
  },
  removeCallback:function (uid, type, callback) {
    if(this.get(uid) && this.get(uid).handlers[type]) {
      let functions = this.get(uid).handlers[type];
      functions.splice(functions.findIndex(callback),1)
    }
  },
  // return element or undefined
  get:function (uid) {
    return this.elements.find(e=>e.uid===uid);
  },

};

/*
* One type could have many event listeners, One element could have many event types of listeners
* So use element.handlers = {'click':[listener1, listener2, ...], 'hover':[...], ...}
* */
let eventListener = (function() {
  let cache = new Cache();

  function add (element, type, callback){
    cache.init(element);
    element.addEventListener(type,element.lqListener);
    if(!element.handlers[type]){
      element.handlers[type] = [];
    }
    (element.handlers[type]).push(callback);
  }

  // remove a type of event listeners, should remove the callback array and remove DOM's event listener
  function removeType (element, type) {
    element.removeEventListener(type,element.lqListener);
    cache.removeType(element.uid,type);
  }

  // remove a event listener, just remove it from the callback array
  function removeCallback(element, type, callback) {
    cache.removeCallback(element.uid,type,callback);
  }

  // bind a callback.
  function on(element,type,callback) {
    if(!(element||type||callback)) throw new Error('Invalid arguments');
    add(element,type,callback);
  }

  function off(element,type,callback) {
    if(!(element instanceof HTMLElement)) throw new Error('Invaild element, need a instance of HMTLElement');
    let handlers = cache.get(element.uid).handlers;

    if(isEmpty(type)&&!callback){
      for(let type in handlers){
        removeType(element,type);
      }
    }
    console.log('off')
    if(!isEmpty(type)&&!callback) removeType(element,type);
    if(!isEmpty(type) && (typeof callback === 'function')) removeCallback(element,type,callback);
  }

  return {
    on,
    off
  }
})();
```

I use chrome debugger to follow `element.handlers`'s value, it seems fine, working great when add and remove callback.

And the testing have some `console.log()` in event's callback function, oddly enough, these `console.log()` do not log in console, and I try to set a breakpoint in callback, it also do not work.

I have little javascript experience, **If anyone can tell me how to debug and where is the bug, thank you very much! And why `console.log()` cannot work in callback.** It should work, since they wrote it in testing, I think.

Here is the testing code:

```
/*global affix*/
/*global eventListener*/

describe('EventListeners', function() {
  'use strict';

  var $selectedElement, selectedElement, methods;

  beforeEach(function() {
    affix('.learn-query-testing #toddler .hidden.toy+h1[class="title"]+span[class="subtitle"]+span[class="subtitle"]+input[name="toyName"][value="cuddle bunny"]+input[class="creature"][value="unicorn"]+.hidden+.infinum[value="awesome cool"]');

    methods = {
      showLove: function(e) {
        console.log('<3 JavaScript <3');
      },

      giveLove: function(e) {
        console.log('==> JavaScript ==>');
        return '==> JavaScript ==>';
      }
    };

    spyOn(methods, 'showLove');
    spyOn(methods, 'giveLove');

    $selectedElement = $('#toddler');
    selectedElement = $selectedElement[0];
  });

  it('should be able to add a click event to an HTML element', function() {
    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'click', methods.showLove);

    $selectedElement.click();

    expect(methods.showLove).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should be able to add the same event+callback two times to an HTML element', function() {
    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'click', methods.showLove);
    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'click', methods.showLove);

    $selectedElement.click();

    expect(methods.showLove.calls.count()).toEqual(2);
  });


  it('should be able to add the same callback for two different events to an HTML element', function() {
    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'click', methods.showLove);
    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'hover', methods.showLove);
    console.log('3')
    $selectedElement.trigger('click');
    $selectedElement.trigger('hover');

    expect(methods.showLove.calls.count()).toEqual(2);
  });

  it('should be able to add two different callbacks for same event to an HTML element', function() {
    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'click', methods.showLove);
    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'click', methods.giveLove);

    $selectedElement.trigger('click');

    expect(methods.showLove.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
    expect(methods.giveLove.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
  });

  it('should be able to remove one event handler of an HTML element', function() {
    $selectedElement.off();

    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'click', methods.showLove);
    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'click', methods.giveLove);
    eventListener.off(selectedElement, 'click', methods.showLove);
    console.log('5')
    $selectedElement.click();

    expect(methods.showLove.calls.count()).toEqual(0);
    expect(methods.giveLove.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
  });

  it('should be able to remove all click events of a HTML element', function() {
    $selectedElement.off();

    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'click', methods.showLove);
    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'click', methods.giveLove);
    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'hover', methods.showLove);

    eventListener.off(selectedElement, 'click');
    console.log('6')

    $selectedElement.trigger('hover');
    $selectedElement.trigger('click');

    expect(methods.showLove.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
    expect(methods.giveLove).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should be able to remove all events of a HTML element', function() {
    $selectedElement.off();

    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'click', methods.showLove);
    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'click', methods.giveLove);
    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'hover', methods.showLove);

    eventListener.off(selectedElement);

    var eventHover = new Event('hover');
    var eventClick = new Event('click');

    selectedElement.dispatchEvent(eventClick);
    selectedElement.dispatchEvent(eventHover);

    expect(methods.showLove).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(methods.giveLove).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should trigger a click event on a HTML element', function() {
    $selectedElement.off();
    $selectedElement.on('click', methods.showLove);

    eventListener.trigger(selectedElement, 'click');

    expect(methods.showLove.calls.count()).toBe(1);
  });

  it('should delegate an event to elements with a given css class name', function() {
    eventListener.delegate(selectedElement, 'title', 'click', methods.showLove);

    $('.title').trigger('click');

    expect(methods.showLove.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
  });

  it('should not delegate an event to elements without a given css class name', function() {
    eventListener.delegate(selectedElement, 'title', 'click', methods.showLove);

    $('.subtitle').trigger('click');
    $('.title').trigger('click');

    expect(methods.showLove.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
  });

  it('should delegate an event to elements that are added to the DOM to after delegate call', function() {
    eventListener.delegate(selectedElement, 'new-element-class', 'click', methods.showLove);

    var newElement = document.createElement('div');
    newElement.className = 'new-element-class';
    $selectedElement.append(newElement);

    $(newElement).trigger('click');

    expect(methods.showLove.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
  });

  it('should trigger delegated event handler when clicked on an element inside a targeted element', function() {
    eventListener.delegate(selectedElement, 'title', 'click', methods.showLove);

    var newElement = document.createElement('div');
    newElement.className = 'new-element-class';
    $selectedElement.append(newElement);

    $('.title').append(newElement);

    $(newElement).trigger('click');

    expect(methods.showLove.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
  });

  it('should not trigger delegated event handler if clicked on container of delegator', function() {
    var $targetElement = $('<p class="target"></p>');
    $selectedElement.append($targetElement);

    eventListener.delegate(selectedElement, 'target', 'click', methods.showLove);

    $selectedElement.click();

    expect(methods.showLove.calls.count()).toEqual(0);
  });

  it('should trigger delegated event handler multiple times if event happens on multiple elements', function() {
    eventListener.delegate(selectedElement, 'subtitle', 'click', methods.showLove);

    $('.subtitle').trigger('click');

    expect(methods.showLove.calls.count()).toEqual(2);
  });

  it('should not trigger method registered on element A when event id triggered on element B', function() {
    var elementA = document.createElement('div');
    var elementB = document.createElement('div');
    $selectedElement.append(elementA);
    $selectedElement.append(elementB);

    eventListener.on(elementA, 'click', methods.showLove);
    eventListener.on(elementB, 'click', methods.giveLove);

    $(elementA).trigger('click');

    expect(methods.showLove).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(methods.giveLove).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Why is there a trailing `})()` at code at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 because testing need use  `eventListener.on()` and `eventListener.off()`, so I use `let eventListener = (function() { ... return {on, off}})()` to call this function, make `eventListener` is an object contains `on` and `off`. Is it a right way?

Comment: Missed viewing `let eventListener = (function() {`, here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the question owner.

After I created a [issue](https://github.com/infinum/learnQuery/issues/6), they fixed the bug in testing. In testing, we can't use our selfmade `on()` and `off()` to add event listeners, then use jQuery's `trigger()` to test it, since jQuery will do some extra works behind. So they replaced it by `dispatchEvent()`.

Also, in my code there are some bugs. As @guest271314 mentioned, I misused `apply()`, should use `call()`, and should use `_Cache` to replace `Cache`. Besides, 
in function `removeCallback`, I misused `functions.findIndex(callback)`, it should be `functions.findIndex(f=>f===callback)`

The correct code is on [this branch](https://github.com/EzioKissshot/LearnQuery/tree/fixed), passed all `on` and `off` testing.

Thanks all of you！

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in that there is no event called `hover`.

Just  a combination of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

You can see all event types listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

When calling `element.addEventListener(type, element.lqListener)`
with type value `hover`, it just does not work.

You can see more info from this question [Is it possible to use jQuery .on and hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover).

Comment: I replace `hover` to other events like `mouseenter` or `dblclick`, it still got same errors. So it might not the `hover` problem, must some bugs in my code.

Comment: Have a new thought, see Update :)

Comment: @EzioShiki  Maybe that is the cause. I debug your code using `mouseenter` and seems the `event.type` is always `click` event the code is actually `$selectedElement.trigger('mouseover');`

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to meeting your own requirement. The only issue that could locate at code,  here, is that [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) expects an `Array` at second parameter

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> func.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])
> ```

Substitute

```
// pass `event` as element to array literal as second parameter to `.apply()`
functions.forEach(f => f.apply(this, [event]));
```

for

```
functions.forEach(f => f.apply(this, event));
```

Also, substituted function name `_Cache` for `Cache`, as [`Cache`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) is a globally defined function

> The **Cache** interface provides a storage mechanism for `Request` /
>   `Response` object pairs that are cached, for example as part of the
>   `ServiceWorker` life cycle.

```js
"use strict";

function isEmpty(str) {
  return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}

// listener use to bind to DOM element, call corresponding functions when event firing.
function geneEventListener(event) {
  console.log('gene');
  let type = Object.keys(this.handlers).find(type => type === event.type);
  if (!type) return;
  let functions = this.handlers[type];
  functions.forEach(f => f.apply(this, [event]));
}

// cache elements which bound event listener
let _Cache = function() {
  this.elements = [];
  this.uid = 1;
};

_Cache.prototype = {
  constructor: _Cache,
  init: function(element) {
    if (!element.uid) element.uid = this.uid++;
    if (!element.handlers) element.handlers = {};
    if (!element.lqListener) element.lqListener = geneEventListener.bind(element);
    this.elements.push(element);
  },
  removeElement: function(uid) {
    this.elements.splice(this.elements.findIndex(e => e.uid === uid), 1);
  },
  removeType: function(uid, type) {
    if (this.get(uid)) delete this.get(uid).handlers[type];
  },
  removeCallback: function(uid, type, callback) {
    if (this.get(uid) && this.get(uid).handlers[type]) {
      let functions = this.get(uid).handlers[type];
      functions.splice(functions.findIndex(callback), 1)
    }
  },
  // return element or undefined
  get: function(uid) {
    return this.elements.find(e => e.uid === uid);
  },

};

/*
 * One type could have many event listeners, One element could have many event types of listeners
 * So use element.handlers = {'click':[listener1, listener2, ...], 'hover':[...], ...}
 * */
let eventListener = (function() {
  let cache = new _Cache();

  function add(element, type, callback) {
    cache.init(element);
    element.addEventListener(type, element.lqListener);
    if (!element.handlers[type]) {
      element.handlers[type] = [];
    }
    (element.handlers[type]).push(callback);
  }

  // remove a type of event listeners, should remove the callback array and remove DOM's event listener
  function removeType(element, type) {
    element.removeEventListener(type, element.lqListener);
    cache.removeType(element.uid, type);
  }

  // remove a event listener, just remove it from the callback array
  function removeCallback(element, type, callback) {
    cache.removeCallback(element.uid, type, callback);
  }

  // bind a callback.
  function on(element, type, callback) {
    if (!(element || type || callback)) throw new Error('Invalid arguments');
    add(element, type, callback);
  }

  function off(element, type, callback) {
    if (!(element instanceof HTMLElement)) throw new Error('Invaild element, need a instance of HMTLElement');
    let handlers = cache.get(element.uid).handlers;

    if (isEmpty(type) && !callback) {
      for (let type in handlers) {
        removeType(element, type);
      }
    }
    console.log('off')
    if (!isEmpty(type) && !callback) removeType(element, type);
    if (!isEmpty(type) && (typeof callback === 'function')) removeCallback(element, type, callback);
  }

  return {
    on,
    off
  }
})();

onload = () => {

eventListener.on(document.querySelector("div"), "click", function(event) {
  console.log(event.type);
  eventListener.off(event.target, "click");
});

}
```

```html
<div>click</div>
```