# How to dynamically change a subcategory?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

[image: This is output of image and which show all category and subcategory]

What I want to achieve is to display all the categories and, when a category is clicked, its relative subcategory should be displayed.

The model view code

```html
    <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->

      <div class="form-group col-md-8">
      <button type="button" class="form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Category  </button>

      <!-- The Modal -->
      <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" >
          <div class="modal-content">
          
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Category</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4" >
                                    <a href="#" name="category" id="category" >            
                                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                                        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->category}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                     </a>
                             
                        </div>
                          <div class="col-md-4 ">
                            <a href="#" name="subcategory" id="subcategory" >
                                @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
                                <option value="{{$subcategory->id}}">{{$subcategory->subcategory}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                             </a>
                                
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                            hhh
                          </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
       
                        $('#category').change(function(){
                var categoryID = $(this).val();
                if(categoryID){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"GET",
                        url:"{{url('/api/getSubcategory/')}}/"+categoryID,

                        success:function(res){

                            if(res){
                                
                                data = JSON.parse(res)
                                $("#subcategory").empty();
                                $("#subcategory").append('<option>Select</option>');
                                $.each(data,function(key,value){
                                    $("#subcategory").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");
                                           
                                });

                            }else{
                                $("#subcategory").empty();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    $("#subcategory").empty();
                }
            });
                    });
</script>
```

The controller code:

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $subcategories = Subcategory::all();

    return view('post.create', compact('categories', 'subcategories'));
}
```

This is the route:

```
Route::get('/post/create', 'PostController@create')->name('post.create');
```

This is the API I created, but I don't know how to use it.

```
public function getSubcategory(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;
    $subcategories = Subcategory::where('category_id',$id)
                         ->select('subcategory','id')
                         ->pluck('subcategory', 'id');
    {{ dd(json_decode($subcategories, true)); }}

    return json_encode($subcategories);
}
```

API route

```
Route::get('api/getSubcategory/{id}', 'PostController@getSubcategory');
```

How can I do this at runtime, when model is changed to a subcategory of its relative category.

Please help me. I am a beginner.

I want to this type of output
[output which i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb8Wx.png)

Comment: Do your Category model and subcategory model have relationships between them?

Comment: yes category model I put this  public function subcategory(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory');
    } -@dilusha_dasanayaka

Comment: @bhavikprajapati check i edit my answer for your storing data in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your dynamic subcategory use below jquery Ajax function

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" >
          <a href="#" name="category" id="category" >            
              @foreach($categories as $category)
              <option class="categoryList" value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->category}}</option> <!-- add conman class for click event --> 
              @endforeach
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 ">
          <a href="#" name="subcategory" id="subcategory" >
          </a>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.categoryList').on('click', function(){
  var cat_id = $(this).attr('value');
  var url = "localhost:8000/api/getSubcategory/"+cat_id;
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(res)
      {
        // amusing res = {"3":"home","4":"home duplex"}; 
        var html = "";
        $.each(res, function (key, value) {
             html += "<option value="+key+">"+value+"</option>";
        });
        $("#subcategory").html(html);
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

If you want to store your data in database then remove model and add below HTML put after your last form input.

```
<div class="col-md-4" >
  <select onchange="selectSubcategory(this)" name="category_id">            
      @foreach($categories as $category)
      <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->category}}</option>
      @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 ">
  <select name="subcategory_id" id="subcategory_id">                                  
  </select>
</div>
```

below code for your dynamic subcategory

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function selectSubcategory(obj){
  var cat_id = $(obj).val();
  var url = "localhost:8000/api/getSubcategory/"+cat_id;
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(res)
      {
        // amusing res = {"3":"home","4":"home duplex"}; 
        var html = "";
        $.each(res, function (key, value) {
             html += "<option value="+key+">"+value+"</option>";
        });
        $("#subcategory_id").html(html);
      }
  });
}
</script>
```

In your controller store method get category and subcategory like below

```
$request->category_id;
$request->subcategory_id;
```

Comment: it show only category...if i click category nothing show anything -

Comment: Have you check in console and what is error show in console ?

Comment: If i put http://localhost:8000/api/getSubcategory/2 in browser than give me this result  {"3":"home","4":"home duplex"}

Comment: ok @bhavikprajapati then use below code in HTML append  ```var html = "";
  $.each(res, function (key, value) {
      html += "<option value="+key+">"+value+"</option>";
  });```

Comment: this response(`{"3":"home","4":"home duplex"}`) come after json parse or before ? if before then show me your console error if after then do JSON.parse(res);

Comment: check this link https://jsfiddle.net/58vc4rep/ if you are not add jquery CDN then add it

Comment: I added   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 see...after it doesn't work

Comment: I checked it and apply but not working...can you help me in remotely?

Comment: You can check..i post answer

Comment: I try it but not save category..infact not select than how could i store? -

Comment: you mean you cant select category ?

Comment: I select category but i can't select subctaegory

Comment: Have you check what is error show in console or API call in inspect->Network ?

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner you can easily do something like this.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4" >

        @foreach($categories as $category)

          <a href="#" name="category" id="category" >                            
              <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->category}}</option>
          </a>

          <div class="col-md-4 ">

            @foreach($category->subcategory as $subcat)
                <a href="#" name="subcategory" class="subcategory" >
                    <option value="{{$subcat->id}}">{{$subcat->subcategory}}</option>                             
                </a>
             @endforeach
         </div>
        @endforeach

      </div>
  </div>
```

If you still want to load subcategories on click/hover events on category item, then you can do it using jquery library. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9827114/41569) tells you about how to do something on mousehover event. Simply call your get subcategory route on that event via ajax, `($.ajax())` and `append` your result.

Comment: I used ajax... I forgot to put..i am going to update question -

Answer (score 0):

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
       <div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" >
          <a href="#" name="category" id="category" >            
              @foreach($categories as $category)
              <option class="categoryList" value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->category}}</option>
              @endforeach
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 ">
          <a href="#" name="subcategory" id="subcategory" >
          </a>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.categoryList').on('click', function(){
  var cat_id = $(this).attr('value');
  var url = "localhost:8000/api/getSubcategory/"+cat_id;
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(res)
      {
        // amusing res = {"3":"home","4":"home duplex"}; 
        var html = "";
        $.each(res, function (key, value) {
             html += "<option value="+key+">"+value+"</option>";
        });
        $("#subcategory").html(html);
      }
  });
});
</script>
@endsection
```

[This is output but not save in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2JHp.png)

Comment: `console.log(cat_id);` put this in below `cat_id` variable and tell me result after click on category list

Comment: I did it...It show nothing on console.. _@PHPHuppTechnologies

Comment: `console.log(123)` put this below `<script type="text/javascript">` and tell me 123 show in your inspect-> console

Comment: error is cors policy..it's working fine now...but i am selecting category and subcategory thats not going in database -@PHPHuppTechnologies

Comment: Yes I post answer..check it but that is not store database ...why? -@PHPHuppTechnologies

Comment: I did it before dropdown list and data store too but i try to modal through and in this data not store -@PHPHuppTechnologies