# How to remove class by hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to set class`aqua` by hovering from `clicked` cells.

I attempt to get`first id` and then change class to `hovering cells`

But, I stacked `removeclass`when `hovering`,

My desired result is to change class from`first`to `last hovered`cells.

Are there any method for them?

Thanks

```js
var first;
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    first = this.id;
    $(this).addClass("aqua");
    console.log(first);
  });
  
  $('td').hover(function() {
  const id = +$(this).attr('id');
  console.log(id);
    
   for(var j=first;j<=id;j++){
   $("#"+id).addClass("aqua");}
                  
});
});
```

```css
.aqua{
  background-color: aqua;
}


td {
  padding: 5px
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td id="1">1</td>
  <td id="2">2</td>
  <td id="3">3</td>
  <td id="4">4</td>
  <td id="5">5</td>
  <td id="6">6</td>
  <td id="7">7</td>
  <td id="8">8</td>
  <td id="9">9</td>
  <td id="10">10</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use jQuery .on and hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover)

Comment: Error in console: `"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: first is not defined",` It is going to throw an error since first is very declared until it is clicked. So you should declare it. Also id is a string, not a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare the variable `first` outside of the click handler function. You also should convert the string *id* to number:

```
const id = Number($(this).attr('id'));
```

```js
$(function() {
  var first;
  $("td").click(function() {
    first = this.id;
    $(this).addClass("aqua");
    console.log(first);
  });
  
  $('td').hover(function() {
    const id = Number($(this).attr('id'));
    console.log(id);

    for(var j = first;j <= id; j++){
      $("#"+id).addClass("aqua");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.aqua{
  background-color: aqua;
}


td {
  padding: 5px
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td id="1">1</td>
  <td id="2">2</td>
  <td id="3">3</td>
  <td id="4">4</td>
  <td id="5">5</td>
  <td id="6">6</td>
  <td id="7">7</td>
  <td id="8">8</td>
  <td id="9">9</td>
  <td id="10">10</td>
</table>
```

Comment: click 2 and hover on 10, You need to convert the string to a number

Comment: Thanks it is very clear , I would like to change class to `last hovered cells`,, if first = 2, and `last hovered cell`=5, even if `6` is hovered, 2,3,4,5 will be changed.

Comment: what's the purpose of that `for` inside the hover function ? why not use a simple `if` ?

Answer (score 1):

THere are a bunch of ways to do this. But i tried to change your initial code as little as i could.

First, you need to convert the `id` ( which are strings ) to numbers. You can do that with parseInt. Because comparing 2 strings is not correct in this situation. Because `'2'<'10'` will return false. String comparison happens on character basis. Which mean each character is compared with the corresponding character from the other string.

So `'2'` is greater > than `'10'` because `'2'` > `'1'` in alphabetical order.

Second, You should remove the `aqua` class from all `td` when clicking again on a `td`.

Third, you do not need a loop. Just check if the current hovered td id is greater than the one you first clicked then add class.

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    const first = parseInt(this.id, 10);
    $(this).addClass("aqua");
    const notThisTd = $('td').not(this)
    notThisTd.removeClass("aqua");
    notThisTd.hover(function() {
      const id = parseInt(this.id, 10);
      if (id > first) {
        $(this).addClass("aqua");
      }

    });


  });
});
```

```css
.aqua{
  background-color: aqua;
}


td {
  padding: 5px
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td id="1">1</td>
  <td id="2">2</td>
  <td id="3">3</td>
  <td id="4">4</td>
  <td id="5">5</td>
  <td id="6">6</td>
  <td id="7">7</td>
  <td id="8">8</td>
  <td id="9">9</td>
  <td id="10">10</td>
</table>
```