# If mouse over for over 2 seconds then show else don't?

Tags: jquery, html, css, timer, slidedown

Here is a jQuery slide function I have applied to a div on hover in order to slide a button down.

It works fine except that now everytime someone moves in and out of it, it keeps bobbing up and down.

I figured if I put a one or two second delay timer on it it would make more sense.

How would I modify the function to run the slide down only if the user is on the div for over a second or two?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#NewsStrip").hover(
function () {
    $("#SeeAllEvents").slideDown('slow');    },
function () {
    $("#SeeAllEvents").slideUp('slow');
});

</script>
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of [jQuery - How to tell .hover() to wait?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089246/jquery-how-to-tell-hover-to-wait)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if you read the question then the OP is not asking exactly that.

Comment: @ThomasClayson: Apparently they are. Same question, same accepted answer.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to set a timer on mouseover and clear it either when the slide is activated or on mouseout, whichever occurs first:

```
var timeoutId;
$("#NewsStrip").hover(function() {
    if (!timeoutId) {
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
            timeoutId = null; // EDIT: added this line
            $("#SeeAllEvents").slideDown('slow');
       }, 2000);
    }
},
function () {
    if (timeoutId) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = null;
    }
    else {
       $("#SeeAllEvents").slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

[**See it in action.**](http://jsfiddle.net/6RKHf/)

Comment: @xDazz Thanks jon and xDazz. The slide down works beautifully but it doesnt slide back up on mouse out? Am I missing or doing something wrong?

Comment: Try getting rid of the `if` `else` blocks in the second function. You don't really need them. Calling those methods like that won't have any detrimental effect if you remove the `if else`. And its probably why its not sliding up again. :)

Comment: @ThomasClayson Well now it slides down and up just once and then goes inactive.Weird

Comment: @user1266515: Fixed a small bug and added a JSFiddle link. How does it look?

Comment: @Jon thank you for sharing some creative power behind using a setTimeout. It  helped me out too.

Answer (score 4):

```
var time_id;

$("#NewsStrip").hover(
function () {
    if (time_id) {
        clearTimeout(time_id);
    } 
    time_id = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#SeeAllEvents").stop(true, true).slideDown('slow');
    }, 2000);
}, function () {
    if (time_id) {
        clearTimeout(time_id);
    } 
    time_id = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#SeeAllEvents").stop(true, true).slideUp('slow');
    }, 2000);
});
```