# How to fade the menu with a small delay?

Tags: jquery, css, fade

When you hover over the #menu it will fadeIn the #menu-big. I want to add a delay when the user moves the mouse away from the #menu-big.

What I have so far works funny (the first time works fine then it won't behave properly): http://jsbin.com/upopap/1

Any ideas?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#menu').hover(
    // mouseover
    function(){
      $('#menu-big').fadeIn('fast');
    },
    // mouseout
    function(){
      setTimeout( function(){
        $('#menu-big').fadeOut('fast')
        }, 1000 );
    }
  );


});
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="menu">
    <div id="menu-big">
      <ul>
        <li><a href=""><span>Meet our Staff</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>Services</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>Associations</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine on Safari fyi

Comment: Same as @0sh on chrome

Comment: firefox also works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a few tries, but I could recreate your issue in Firefox.
I think this may be closer to what you were looking for:

[**Basic Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/mATZ7/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu').mouseenter(function () {
        $('#menu-big').fadeIn(400);
    });
    $('#menu').mouseleave(function () {
        $('#menu-big').delay(800).fadeOut(400);
    });
});
```

[API documentaion for .delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

The basic version will cover what you were asking for, but you may want to use the advanced version as it has a delay before firing the hover event which will resolve an issue with moving the mouse in and out of `#menu-big` quickly.

[**Advanced Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/mATZ7/2/)

```
$(function() {
    var timeoutId;
    $("#menu").hover(function() {
        if (!timeoutId) {
            timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
                timeoutId = null;
                $("#menu-big").fadeIn('slow');
           }, 1000);
        }
    },
    function () {
        if (timeoutId) {
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            timeoutId = null;
        }
        else {
           $("#menu-big").delay(800).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

This method is an adaptation from [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11263756/1947286) if it works for you you may want to through an up-vote on it as well.