# Jquery wait 3 seconds after mouseover

Tags: jquery

I have got this jquery code

```
$(".y_e").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).children(".Photopreview").show("fast");
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).children(".Photopreview").hide("fast");
        })
});
```

and this html

```
     <div class="y_e">
       <div class="Photopreview">
         <img src="../uploads/a.jpg"/>
         <div class="Arrow_down" ></div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

How can i wait 3 seconds after user mouseovers on y_e?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If mouse over for over 2 seconds then show else dont?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263636/if-mouse-over-for-over-2-seconds-then-show-else-dont)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "delay" jquery method like the following code

```
$(".y_e").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).children(".Photopreview").stop(true,true).delay(3000).show("fast");
});
$(this).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).children(".Photopreview").stop(true,true).hide("fast");
});
```

Note: don't register event listener inside other event listener, because this will register multiple listeners for same event type.

Comment: You should change $(this).mousleave to$(".y_e").mouseleave

Answer (score 2):

You can use setTimeout for waiting purposes.

```
$('.y_e').mouseover(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // The stuff you want to do when your three seconds are over.
  }, 3000)
});
```

Comment: then if i mouseout in that 3000 it will still show it

Comment: The function inside setTimeout is immediately "activated" when you do a mouseover, but only executed after 3 seconds. No matter where your mouse is then.

Comment: That is why i am looking for other way

Comment: You might want to clarify what you're really after.

Comment: I did not get what you said

Answer (score 1):

Try implement setTimeout with an anonymous function

```
$(".y_e").mouseover(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).children(".Photopreview").show("fast");
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).children(".Photopreview").hide("fast");
        })        
    }, 3000);
});
```