# How to add setimeout on html

Tags: html, angular

I need to call mouseHoverTableRow() function after hovering on tr 3 seconds.
If hovering is less than 3 second than I don't want to call mouseHoverTableRow(). I am calling API on mouseHoverTableRow()
How to do that?

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of list" (mouseover)= "window.setTimeout('mouseHoverTableRow(item.id)', 3000)">
<td></td>
</tr
```

Comment: use rxjs timeout operator. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/timeout.html

Comment: The same issue already answers here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11263756/3169136. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to use `setTimeout` in html directly,so instead of doing above you can write that same logic inside your

> typescript file

```
 onMouseHover(id) {
    setTimeout ((id) => {
         this.mouseHoverTableRow(id)
      }, 3000);
  }

  mouseHoverTableRow(id:number){
  // your function body
  }
```

and then

> in html

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of list" (mouseover)= "onMouseHover(item?.id)">
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Above code snippet execute after 3 seconds when the user hovers on `tr`, this is not the issue. The issue is when user hover for 3 seconds on a `tr` then the code should be executed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**.ts**

```
let timer;  // global timer

 onMouseHover(id) {

    this.clearTimer(); // clear your existing timer

    this.timer = setTimeout ((id) => { // set timer
         this.mouseHoverTableRow(id)
      }, 3000);
  }

 clearTimer(){
    // clear your timer
    if(this.timer)
       clearTimeout(this.timer)
 }

  mouseHoverTableRow(id:number){
  // your function body
  }
```

**.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of list" (mouseover)= "onMouseHover(item?.id)" (mouseout)="clearTimer()">
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It is still calling if I hover less than 3000.

Comment: @Mini have a look at [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axfabu)