# how to add if condition for mouseover (cursor) exceeds three scond in a "a tag"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, jquery-hover

My question is not a time duration of animation.
My question is - If mouse is stay more than 3 second in  TAG. Hover effect  will come, but never load the data before 3 second. So load the data after 3 seonds only. From my end below are my html code and i can't add class name and id name because all are dynamic

Html:

```
 <a href="#" style="display: inline !important; cursor:pointer;">
   <div onmouseover="Snapshot("some backend data")"></div>
</a>
```

This type of structure i am looking.

```
if (time >= 3000s)
{
add data
}
else
{
add another
}
```

Comment: *"can't add class/id"* - is there some other way to identify the div in question?  Can you add a `data-` attribute?  Does it have a parent with a known id/class? parent-parent(-parent..) etc?  "*because all are dynamic*" - including the `onmouseover` and the `style=inline etc` - being dynamic shouldn't stop you adding a class somewhere unless there's some other restriction that just "being dynamic"

Comment: What have you tried so far?  SetTimout / ClearTimeout seem the obvious solution.

Comment: @freedomn-m I am going to add this if contion code inside Function(Snapshot) also that snapshot function is global.

Comment: Refer to this answer.....
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263636/if-mouse-over-for-over-2-seconds-then-show-else-dont)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a function for the mouseover event that starts a timer. If that timer reaches 3000ms, or more, then call the function to update whatever it is you are updating.

Also create a mouseout event that clears the timeout.

```html
<a href="#" onmouseover="snapshot('some backend data')" onmouseout="clearSnapshotTimeout()">Move your cursor and wait 3 seconds</a>
```

```js
var snapshotTimeout;

// code that deals with (loads) data here.
function snapshot(data) {
    snapshotTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
        alert('alert happens after 3 seconds');
    }, 3000);
}

function clearSnapshotTimeout() {
    window.clearTimeout(snapshotTimeout);
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you cannot add a mouseout event to the html pages then you could try this:

```html
<a href="#" onmouseover="snapshot('some backend data')">Move your cursor and wait 3 seconds</a>
```

```js
var snapshotTimeout;
// code that deals with (loads) data here.
function snapshot(data) {
    snapshotTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
        alert('alert happens after 3 seconds');
    }, 3000);
}

function clearSnapshotTimeout() {
    window.clearTimeout(snapshotTimeout);
}

// add the mouseout event handler to each element that has a mouseover attribute.
var mouseOverElements = document.querySelectorAll('[onmouseover^="snapshot("');

for(var i=0;i<mouseOverElements.length;i++) {
  console.log(mouseOverElements[i]);
    mouseOverElements[i].onmouseout = function() {
        clearSnapshotTimeout();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's almost working but myself I need if conditon because if I implement your code then I am going to add onmouseout="clearSnapshotTimeout()" around hundred pages.

Comment: load the data after completion of 3 second but from your code is not like that. It's load the data when mouse hover and show the alert after 3 second. This is the issue. That's why I am looking If condition...

Comment: I have edited my answer to accommodate for adding a mouseout event to each element.

Comment: Hi Adrian, Html with onmouseout only working but html without onmouseout is not working. Please check.

Comment: Working example here: https://codepen.io/adrianroworth/pen/MWWxBOd, and there was a small error in my selector (my fault), fixed in the linked demo, and the example above.

Comment: I checked and implemented with my code, it's still load the data before 3 second but If i added onmouseout, it's working good. Finding mouseover attribute is not working. console.log is also not working.....

Comment: Now I added onmouseover effect on all my static and dynamic pages. Now it's working good. Thanks for saving my time @Adrian Roworth.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, you have to have some unique feature to your `a` tag such as a class/id/data attribute to be able to pinpoint it in Javascript. Otherwise the only way for you would be for all your `a` tags to react to the behavior you want to create.

There should be a way for you to do that I hope.

So let's say you've given an `id` to your `a` tag. You should be able to do this.

```
const myLink = document.getElementById('myId');

let timeout;

myLink.on('mouseover', () => {
    timeout = window.setTimeout(() => doStuff);
});

myLink.on('mouseout'), () => {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
});

function doStuff () {
   // Your logic here
}
```