# Jquery hover delay best method?

Tags: jquery, hover, delay

I am trying to figure out the best way to make my project work.

Please view my bootply: http://www.bootply.com/119281 (bootply because its for a bootstrap project)

Here's a breakdown of what i want it to do:

1. On pageload the bottom bar is visible at a "full" height. 
   if there is no mouse enter within 5 seconds it will close to a "Mid" height, just show the heading.
2. On mouseover, the bottom bar will go back to "full" height it was at pageload.
3. On mouseout, there will be a delay before the bottom bar goes to "mid" height.
4. While the bottom bar is at "full" height, columns inside the bar will also have there own animation. I am using css for the column animations.

The one i coded is ok but a bit jerky (but only sometimes).

I would like to know if im doing this correct or is there another way to accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Mahalo in advance!

Comment: #1 use a simple setInterval that checks a recorded hover timestamp. #2-4 http://stackoverflow.com/a/1089381/37055

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell .hover() to wait?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089246/how-to-tell-hover-to-wait)